# Generate Url to Razor Page in Area from Razor View

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, routes, razor-pages

Within Razor **View**, I want to generate Url to specific Razor **Page** which is located in some **Area**.

I have already trying using this

```
@Url.Page("/Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Manage/Orders", new { id = @Model.Id })
```

but what I get in return is

```
http://localhost:8888/Order/Submit/12345?page=%2FAreas%2FIdentity%2FPages%2FAccount%2FManage%2FOrders
```

while I would need this:

```
http://localhost:8888/Identity/Account/Manage/Orders?id=12345
```

Is it correct to assume that the only way to solve it is to apply customer routing? If yes, what would be the way? Thanks.

Comment: `@Url.Page("/Pages/Account/Manage/Orders", new { area = "Identity", id = @Model.Id })` should do it, I think.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure you need `/Pages` at the start either...

Comment: without `/Pages` that works! thank you very much :)

Answer (score 11):

This should do the trick:

```
@Url.Page("/Account/Manage/Orders", new { id = Model.Id, area = "Identity"})
```

Answer (score 0):

`PageLink` creates only absolute URLs.

```
@Url.PageLink(
    "Pages/Account/Manage/Orders",
    values: new { area = "Identity", id = @Model.Id });
```